# Group Chat Application

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to make an android group chat application using firebase by using udacity (Firebase in a weekend)
I have followed every step but my data is not going into database.
I am sharing my code with you please tell me where i am going wrong .
I have changed the authentication rules in the firebase and set them to true for read and write.

```
 mUsername = ANONYMOUS;
    mFirebaseDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    mMessagesDatabaseRference = mFirebaseDatabase.getReference().child("messages");


    // Initialize references to views
    mProgressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
    mMessageListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.messageListView);
    mPhotoPickerButton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.photoPickerButton);
    mMessageEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.messageEditText);
    mSendButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.sendButton);
    mSendButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            FriendlyMessage friendlyMessage = new FriendlyMessage(mMessageEditText.getText().toString(), mUsername, null);
            mMessagesDatabaseRference.push().setValue(friendlyMessage);

            // Clear input box
            mMessageEditText.setText("");
        }
    });
```

This is my build.gradle file dependencies

```
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    //noinspection GradleCompatible
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:12.0.1'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.6.1'
}
```

This is project level gradle file...
    buildscript {

```
repositories {
    jcenter()
    mavenLocal()
    google()
}
dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.1.0'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}
```

And this is main activity layout file...

```
 <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/photoPickerButton"
        android:layout_width="36dp"
        android:layout_height="36dp"
        android:background="@android:drawable/ic_menu_gallery" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/messageEditText"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/sendButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:enabled="false"
        android:text="Send"/>
```

Manifest.xml

```
 <application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/Base.Theme.AppCompat.Light">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

Friendly message code

```
public class FriendlyMessage {
    private String text;
    private String name;
    private String photoUrl;

    public FriendlyMessage() {
    }

    public FriendlyMessage(String text, String name, String photoUrl) {
        this.text = text;
        this.name = name;
        this.photoUrl = photoUrl;
    }

    public String getText() {
        return text;
    }

    public void setText(String text) {
        this.text = text;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getPhotoUrl() {
        return photoUrl;
    }

    public void setPhotoUrl(String photoUrl) {
        this.photoUrl = photoUrl;}
    }
```

[Database structure should look like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mpRJA.png)

Comment: I have already done this . I have changed the database rules

Comment: share your database structure and FriendlyMessage class code

Comment: I have added the code in my question. and Data will be entered fr the first time it should look like normal database

Comment: Have you added the "google-services.json" to your project in Android Studio, most of your code looks ok.
What messages do you get in the Logcat?

Comment: ya i have added in debug folder inide folder @Racu

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried adding internet permission on the manifest?

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

In case this not work, you should provide more relevant information as the logcat during the execution. In case of an error with database permission, in fact, an error message on the log is provided by Firebase Database.

Comment: I forgot to add internet permission. But now I have added but still not getting anything on the database .

Comment: DO i need to do anything specific???Actually I have taken this code from udacity but it is not working anywhere ..Is there any mistake in code ?? or am i missing anything else??

Comment: As I said, you should also provide some information about your logcat in order to understand if something is going on

Answer (score 0):

Make FriendlyMessage model members public !

```
public class FriendlyMessage {
    public String text;
    public String name;
    public String photoUrl;

    public FriendlyMessage() {
    }

    public FriendlyMessage(String text, String name, String photoUrl) {
        this.text = text;
        this.name = name;
        this.photoUrl = photoUrl;
    }

    public String getText() {
        return text;
    }

    public void setText(String text) {
        this.text = text;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getPhotoUrl() {
        return photoUrl;
    }

    public void setPhotoUrl(String photoUrl) {
        this.photoUrl = photoUrl;}
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to give specific Database url to FireDatabase like below :

```
mFirebaseDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance("https://xxxx-d9b10.firebaseio.com");
```

and that url will be find in this [Firebase](https://console.firebase.google.com). then select your project if you have already created project. otherwise you should to create project. After selecting or creating project go to "database" from left hand side menu where you will find the url(like i have mentioned above) for firebase database.

Comment: can you give me the url of your project ? i will check and let you know

Answer (score 0):

Try with this :

```
 mUsername = ANONYMOUS;

private DatabaseReference mMessagesDatabaseRference;

mMessagesDatabaseRference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();

// Initialize references to views
mProgressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
mMessageListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.messageListView);
mPhotoPickerButton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.photoPickerButton);
mMessageEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.messageEditText);
mSendButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.sendButton);
mSendButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {

        DatabaseReference mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("messages");

        String userId = mDatabase.push().getKey();


        FriendlyMessage friendlyMessage = new FriendlyMessage(mMessageEditText.getText().toString(), mUsername, null);


        mDatabase.child(userId).setValue(friendlyMessage);
        mMessageEditText.setText("");
    }
});
```

and make model class `FriendlyMessage`variables public. [for more help check this link](https://www.androidhive.info/2016/10/android-working-with-firebase-realtime-database/)

Comment: Not working for my application.. I don't know what is the problem??